# FlatMapLatest not concatenating correctly

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin-coroutines

I want to flatMapLatest multiple flows together, However, when doing the concatenation i don't get anything when collecting the data.

```
  fun getFlows(DataList: List<Data>): Flow<List<Data>> {
        var flow = flow<List<Data>> { }
        matchList.map { it.id }.forEach { id ->
            flow = flow.flatMapLatest {
                getFlow(dataId) 
            }
        }
        Timber.e(flow.toString())
        flow.onEach { // Here we get same result if we have it inside a scope and collect
            Timber.e(it.toString())
        }
        return flow
    }
```

`getData()` returns a `callbackFlow` of Data. which originates from a firebase subscription.

When running the code I receive this log:

```
kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow@c04c419 -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2] -> ChannelFlowTransformLatest[capacity=-2]
```

The value from onEach don't log anything

The `getData` works if I manually hardcode flows together with flatMapLatest without doing the forEach

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> The getData works if I manually hardcode flows together with flatMapLatest without doing the forEach

I doubt this would be functionally equivalent since there is no way a flow constructed from `flow {}` and `flatMapLatest` calls can result in any data.

This is because `flatMapLatest` only fires if the source flow emits something. Since your initial `flow` just immediately exits it never emits anything and terminates the final flow.

Furthermore the results of your `getFlow(dataId)` call within `flatMapLatest` would end up being the input parameter for the following `flatMapLatest` call and get dropped.

Finally `Flow` are not executed until they are collected, so your call to `flow.onEach` does nothing and is immediately garbage collected.

To actually get a concatenation of all the queried data can be very simple:

```kotlin
val flow = matchList.asFlow().map { it.id }.flatMapConcat { getFlow(it) }
Timber.e(flow.toString())
return flow.onEach {
    Timber.e(it.toString())
}
```